# Using translation in observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, internationalization, observers

I started cleaning up my models and controllers by outsourcing the sending of notification mails into an observer.

There is one problem I noticed by moving this from controller to observer:
If I call 'translate' or the shorthand 't' I get the answer "Method not defined"

Ok, I really like the rails implementation for internationalisation.
But how can it be used in models and observers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method via the I18n object:

```
I18n.t :whatever
```